# Getting some errors while trying to get rss feed from url, nevertheless on localhost everything works fine

Tags: php, rss, rss-reader

I appreciate you taking the time to try to help me with my problem. Well my problem is that I am trying to get news rss feed so I built my script (I am an amateur with rss feed stuff more than beginner a bit) so when i run the script to save the rss feed to my database on my localhost laptop everything works fine and the link in the error works fine and is accessible however when i upload it to my online host it is giving me this error:

> Warning: simplexml_load_file(https://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/World.xml): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in /home/vol15_7/byethost7.com/b7_27905999/htdocs/cron/news_cron_1.php on line 24

> Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "https://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/World.xml" in /home/vol15_7/byethost7.com/b7_27905999/htdocs/cron/news_cron_1.php on line 24
> Operation failed
> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/vol15_7/byethost7.com/b7_27905999/htdocs/cron/news_cron_1.php on line 42

I tried many solution found online by doing google search but none worked so I decided to create a new post for this, I hope it would give something to the community and help others who are having such a problem.

here are my code for the rss catcher and inserting into database:

```
$sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM news_feeds_list WHERE cron_file = '1' ORDER BY cron_timestamp ASC";
$query = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlCommand);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
   $feed_id = $row["feed_id"];
   $feed_title = html_entity_decode($row["feed_title"]);
   $feed_name = $row["feed_name"];
   $feed_url = $row["feed_url"];
   $feed_region = $row["feed_region"];
   $feed_length = $row["feed_length"];
   $feed_notes = $row["feed_notes"];
   $feed_subject = $row["feed_subject"];

   //libxml_get_errors();

   // Here we insert the news into database
   $url = "$feed_url";
   $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

    if($xml === false){
        echo "Operation failed";
        continue;
    } else {

        for($i = 0; $i < $feed_length; $i++) {
            $title = $xml->channel->item[$i]->title;
            $description = $xml->channel->item[$i]->description;
            $link = $xml->channel->item[$i]->link;
            $pubDate = $xml->channel->item[$i]->pubDate;
            //$author = $xml->channel->item[$i]->author;
            $author = '';
            $title1 = str_replace("'", "\'", $title);
            $description1 = strip_tags($description, '<p><b>');
            $description1 = str_replace("'", "\'", $description1);
            $author1 = str_replace("'", "\'", $author);
            $feed_source_image = $xml->channel->item[$i]->image['url'][0];
            $feed_image = $xml->channel->item[$i]->enclosure['url'][0];
            $news_timestamp = time();
        
            if($feed_image == ""){
                $feed_image = "";
            }

            // Here we convert pubDate which is a string to a timestamp
            $time = strtotime($pubDate);
        
            if($feed_subject == "Politics") {
                // IGNORE in the sql query is very important to not insert a duplicate, so it will insert a story once only
                $query1 = "INSERT IGNORE INTO news_feeds 
                        (feeds_id, pubDate, news_title, description, 
                        link, author, location, feed_name, feed_subject, 
                        news_timestamp, feed_source_image, 
                        news_image_link) 
                    VALUES($feed_id, '$time', '$title1', '$description1', 
                            '$link', '$author1', '$feed_region', 
                            '$feed_name', 'Politics', $news_timestamp, 
                            '$feed_source_image', '$feed_image')";
                $result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $query1);
            } else if($feed_subject == "Science") {
                // IGNORE in the sql query is very important to not insert a duplicate, so it will insert a story once only
                $query1 = "INSERT IGNORE INTO news_feeds 
                            (feeds_id, pubDate, news_title, description, 
                            link, author, location, feed_name, 
                            feed_subject, news_timestamp, 
                            feed_source_image, news_image_link) 
                        VALUES($feed_id, '$time', '$title1', 
                        '$description1', '$link', '$author1', 
                        '$feed_region', '$feed_name', 'Science', 
                        $news_timestamp, '$feed_source_image', 
                        '$feed_image')";
                $result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $query1);
            } else if($feed_subject == "Technology") {
                // IGNORE in the sql query is very important to not insert a duplicate, so it will insert a story once only
                $query1 = "INSERT IGNORE INTO news_feeds (feeds_id, pubDate, news_title, description, link, author, location, feed_name, feed_subject, news_timestamp, feed_source_image, news_image_link) VALUES($feed_id, '$time', '$title1', '$description1', '$link', '$author1', '$feed_region', '$feed_name', 'Technology', $news_timestamp, '$feed_source_image', '$feed_image')";
                $result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $query1);
            } else if($feed_subject == "World News") {
                // IGNORE in the sql query is very important to not insert a duplicate, so it will insert a story once only
                $query1 = "INSERT IGNORE INTO news_feeds (feeds_id, pubDate, news_title, description, link, author, location, feed_name, feed_subject, news_timestamp, feed_source_image, news_image_link) VALUES($feed_id, '$time', '$title1', '$description1', '$link', '$author1', '$feed_region', '$feed_name', 'World News', $news_timestamp, '$feed_source_image', '$feed_image')";
                $result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $query1);
            } else if($feed_subject == "Sports") {
                // IGNORE in the sql query is very important to not insert a duplicate, so it will insert a story once only
                $result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $query1);
            }
         }
      }
    
     }
     mysqli_free_result($query);
```

Comment: I think *HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden* is probably the most relevant part of the error message.

Comment: but the funny thing is that when i run it on my localhost machine (laptop) the script runs without this error and i get news inserted into my database

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: 403, maybe they a fedup with you nicking their content. 403 means they are there and understand your request but dont want to serve the reply

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for your advice, i will work on it. About the 403, i don't understand why it works on localhost and not online ? and about the link, if you take it and paste it in the browser, it opens normally why is that if it is forbidden ?